# How to remove the item and refresh the list of dropdown value in js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is my code

```
<div class="addParamsInput">
       <div class="display-flex flex-12 addParamsRow added text-left" id="addParamsRow-1"></div>
       <div class="display-flex flex-12 addParamsRow added text-left" style="margin-top: 15px" id="addParamsRow-2"> </div>
      <div class="display-flex flex-12 addParamsRow added text-left" style="margin-top: 15px" id="addParamsRow-3"> </div>
       <div class="display-flex flex-12 addParamsRow added text-left" style="margin-top: 15px" id="addParamsRow-4"></div>
       <div class="display-flex flex-12 addParamsRow added text-left" style="margin-top: 15px" id="addParamsRow-5"> </div>
      </div>
```

when I try to delete id = "addParamsRow-4" again the list should get refreshed. Instead when I add new row it is build like below code

```
<div class="addParamsInput">
       <div class="display-flex flex-12 addParamsRow added text-left" id="addParamsRow-1"></div>
       <div class="display-flex flex-12 addParamsRow added text-left" style="margin-top: 15px" id="addParamsRow-2"> </div>
      <div class="display-flex flex-12 addParamsRow added text-left" style="margin-top: 15px" id="addParamsRow-3"> </div>
       <div class="display-flex flex-12 addParamsRow added text-left" style="margin-top: 15px" id="addParamsRow-5"> </div>
       <div class="display-flex flex-12 addParamsRow added text-left" style="margin-top: 15px" id="addParamsRow-5"> </div>
      </div>
```

Thanks in Advance

Js Changes

```
var createAnotherParamCol = function(){
var newParamColRow = $('.addParamsRow').clone();    

var rowLength = newParamColRow.length;

console.log('Inside the createAnotherParamCol..........................', rowLength);

var eleId = "addParamsRow-"+(rowLength+1);
var paramColListEleId = "paramColList-"+(rowLength+1);
newParamColRow = '<div class="display-flex flex-12 addParamsRow added text-left" style = "margin-top: 15px" >'
                 +' <div class="flex-5" style = "margin-right: 15px">'
                 +'<select name="paramsColName" class="paramColList" id = "'+paramColListEleId+'"></select>'
                 +'</div>'
                 +'<div class="flex-5" style = "margin-right: 15px"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOptionName" placeholder="Enter your value..."></div>'
                 +'<div class="flex-1">'
                 +'<button class="add-params" title ="Add Column" type="button" onclick="createAnotherParamCol()"><i class="fa fa-plus"  style = "padding-top: 5px"></i></button>'
                 +'</div>'
                 +'<div class="flex-1">'
                 +'<button class="delete-params" title ="Delete" type="button" onclick="deleteParamCol(this.name)" name = "'+eleId+'"><i class="fa fa-trash"  style = "padding-top: 5px"></i></button>'
                 +' </div>  </div>';

$(".addParamsInput").append($(newParamColRow).attr("id", eleId));
askingParams(paramColListEleId);
$("#paramsColName").multipleSelect("refresh");}


var deleteParamCol = function(ele){
$("#"+ele).remove();}
```

Comment: Can you also share with us the js code you are using?

Comment: edited and added

Comment: Hi, here you need to make these `ddParamsRow-5` values in sequence  ?

Comment: Yes need like that...